# Dynamically Deserialize Json To List<T> Type in C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have this xml sample and I want to Deserialize it into List of T Type using C#
it contains elements or Items and their details, there might be 1 or more items(1) in the list, so I want to get it as List

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<QBPOSXML>
    <QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
        <SalesOrderQueryRs requestID="809150883" retCount="4" statusCode="0" statusMessage="Status OK" statusSeverity="Info">
            <SalesOrderRet>
                <TxnID>2425100528976298241</TxnID>
                <TimeModified>2018-05-24T13:40:31-04:00</TimeModified>
                <BalanceDue>83.60</BalanceDue>
                <CustomerListID>2421462034504646913</CustomerListID>
                <DepositBalance>0.00</DepositBalance>
                <Discount>0.00</Discount>
                <DiscountPercent>0.00</DiscountPercent>
                <ItemsCount>1</ItemsCount>
                <PriceLevelNumber>1</PriceLevelNumber>
                <Qty>1.00</Qty>
                <SalesOrderNumber>6</SalesOrderNumber>
                <SalesOrderStatusDesc>Open</SalesOrderStatusDesc>
                <StoreExchangeStatus>Modified</StoreExchangeStatus>
                <Subtotal>77.77</Subtotal>
                <TaxAmount>5.83</TaxAmount>
                <TaxCategory>Local Sales Tax</TaxCategory>
                <TaxPercentage>7.50</TaxPercentage>
                <Total>83.60</Total>
                <TxnDate>2018-05-24</TxnDate>
                <UnfilledPercent>100.00</UnfilledPercent>
                <BillingInformation>
    <CompanyName>SimboliQ</CompanyName>
    <FirstName>Basel</FirstName>
    <LastName>Abdo</LastName>
                </BillingInformation>
                <ShippingInformation>
    <Shipping>0.00</Shipping>
                </ShippingInformation>
                <SalesOrderItemRet>
    <ListID>5523943615132238081</ListID>
    <TxnLineID>1</TxnLineID>
    <ALU>YX650-15532</ALU>
    <Attribute>15.5</Attribute>
    <Commission>0.00</Commission>
    <Desc1>Youth Baseball Bat</Desc1>
    <Desc2>Metal</Desc2>
    <Discount>0.00</Discount>
    <DiscountPercent>0.00</DiscountPercent>
    <ExtendedPrice>77.77</ExtendedPrice>
    <ExtendedTax>5.83</ExtendedTax>
    <ItemNumber>21</ItemNumber>
    <Price>77.77</Price>
    <PriceLevelNumber>1</PriceLevelNumber>
    <Qty>1.00</Qty>
    <Size>32 in</Size>
    <TaxAmount>5.83</TaxAmount>
    <TaxCode>Tax</TaxCode>
    <TaxPercentage>7.50</TaxPercentage>
                </SalesOrderItemRet>
            </SalesOrderRet>
            <SalesOrderRet>
                <TxnID>5835181227425825025</TxnID>
                <TimeModified>2010-11-16T09:04:25-04:00</TimeModified>
                <Associate>BrianS</Associate>
                <BalanceDue>242.95</BalanceDue>
                <Cashier>BrianS</Cashier>
                <CustomerListID>5515925198240383233</CustomerListID>
                <DepositBalance>0.00</DepositBalance>
                <Discount>26.99</Discount>
                <DiscountPercent>10.00</DiscountPercent>
                <ItemsCount>3</ItemsCount>
                <PriceLevelNumber>1</PriceLevelNumber>
                <Qty>3.00</Qty>
                <SalesOrderNumber>1</SalesOrderNumber>
                <SalesOrderStatusDesc>Open</SalesOrderStatusDesc>
                <StoreExchangeStatus>Modified</StoreExchangeStatus>
                <Subtotal>269.94</Subtotal>
                <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
                <TaxCategory>Local Sales Tax</TaxCategory>
                <TaxPercentage>0.00</TaxPercentage>
                <Total>242.95</Total>
                <TxnDate>2010-11-16</TxnDate>
                <UnfilledPercent>100.00</UnfilledPercent>
                <BillingInformation>
    <City>Mountain View</City>
    <FirstName>99999</FirstName>
    <LastName>9999</LastName>
    <Phone>9999999</Phone>
    <PostalCode>94040</PostalCode>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Street>1005 Lily Blvd.</Street>
                </BillingInformation>
                <ShippingInformation>
    <City>Mountain View</City>
    <FullName>Michael Beene</FullName>
    <Phone>99999-2214</Phone>
    <PostalCode>6363</PostalCode>
    <ShipBy>FedEx Home Delivery®</ShipBy>
    <Shipping>0.00</Shipping>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Street>1005 Lily Blvd.</Street>
                </ShippingInformation>
                <SalesOrderItemRet>
    <ListID>5523943646161699073</ListID>
    <TxnLineID>1</TxnLineID>
    <ALU>PRSC48-12</ALU>
    <Associate>BrianS</Associate>
    <Attribute>Left</Attribute>
    <Commission>9.00</Commission>
    <Desc1>Adult Baseball Glove</Desc1>
    <Discount>0.00</Discount>
    <DiscountPercent>0.00</DiscountPercent>
    <ExtendedPrice>89.98</ExtendedPrice>
    <ExtendedTax>0.00</ExtendedTax>
    <ItemNumber>78</ItemNumber>
    <Price>89.98</Price>
    <PriceLevelNumber>1</PriceLevelNumber>
    <Qty>1.00</Qty>
    <Size>12</Size>
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
    <TaxCode>Tax</TaxCode>
    <TaxPercentage>0.00</TaxPercentage>
                </SalesOrderItemRet>
                <SalesOrderItemRet>
    <ListID>5523943641824788737</ListID>
    <TxnLineID>2</TxnLineID>
    <ALU>PRSC48-1125</ALU>
    <Associate>BrianS</Associate>
    <Attribute>Left</Attribute>
    <Commission>9.00</Commission>
    <Desc1>Adult Baseball Glove</Desc1>
    <Discount>0.00</Discount>
    <DiscountPercent>0.00</DiscountPercent>
    <ExtendedPrice>89.98</ExtendedPrice>
    <ExtendedTax>0.00</ExtendedTax>
    <ItemNumber>76</ItemNumber>
    <Price>89.98</Price>
    <PriceLevelNumber>1</PriceLevelNumber>
    <Qty>1.00</Qty>
    <Size>11 1/4</Size>
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
    <TaxCode>Tax</TaxCode>
    <TaxPercentage>0.00</TaxPercentage>
                </SalesOrderItemRet>
                <SalesOrderItemRet>
    <ListID>5523943646195253505</ListID>
    <TxnLineID>3</TxnLineID>
    <ALU>PRSC48-1275</ALU>
    <Associate>BrianS</Associate>
    <Attribute>Left</Attribute>
    <Commission>9.00</Commission>
    <Desc1>Adult Baseball Glove</Desc1>
    <Discount>0.00</Discount>
    <DiscountPercent>0.00</DiscountPercent>
    <ExtendedPrice>89.98</ExtendedPrice>
    <ExtendedTax>0.00</ExtendedTax>
    <ItemNumber>80</ItemNumber>
    <Price>89.98</Price>
    <PriceLevelNumber>1</PriceLevelNumber>
    <Qty>1.00</Qty>
    <Size>12 3/4</Size>
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
    <TaxCode>Tax</TaxCode>
    <TaxPercentage>0.00</TaxPercentage>
                </SalesOrderItemRet>
            </SalesOrderRet>
                <TxnID>5835195847536443649</TxnID>
                <TimeModified>2010-12-18T08:45:23-04:00</TimeModified>
                <BalanceDue>807.97</BalanceDue>
                <CustomerListID>5515925198240383233</CustomerListID>
                <DepositBalance>0.00</DepositBalance>
                <Discount>42.53</Discount>
                <DiscountPercent>5.00</DiscountPercent>
                <ItemsCount>4</ItemsCount>
                <PriceLevelNumber>3</PriceLevelNumber>
                <Qty>7.00</Qty>
                <SalesOrderNumber>1</SalesOrderNumber>
                <SalesOrderStatusDesc>Open</SalesOrderStatusDesc>
                <StoreExchangeStatus>Modified</StoreExchangeStatus>
                <Subtotal>850.50</Subtotal>
                <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
                <TaxCategory>Local Sales Tax</TaxCategory>
                <TaxPercentage>0.00</TaxPercentage>
                <Total>807.97</Total>
                <TxnDate>2010-12-18</TxnDate>
                <UnfilledPercent>100.00</UnfilledPercent>
                <BillingInformation>
    <City>Mountain View</City>
    <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
    <LastName>Beene</LastName>
    <Phone>464646</Phone>
    <PostalCode>94040</PostalCode>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Street>1005 Lily Blvd.</Street>
                </BillingInformation>
                <ShippingInformation>
    <Shipping>0.00</Shipping>
                </ShippingInformation>
                <SalesOrderItemRet>
    <ListID>5757732990096408833</ListID>
    <TxnLineID>1</TxnLineID>
    <ALU>34530-22-STR</ALU>
    <Attribute>Red/Wht/Bl</Attribute>
    <Commission>0.00</Commission>
    <Desc1>Wet Suit</Desc1>
    <Discount>0.00</Discount>
    <DiscountPercent>0.00</DiscountPercent>
    <ExtendedPrice>243.00</ExtendedPrice>
    <ExtendedTax>0.00</ExtendedTax>
    <ItemNumber>309</ItemNumber>
    <Price>121.50</Price>
    <PriceLevelNumber>3</PriceLevelNumber>
    <Qty>2.00</Qty>
    <Size>XXL</Size>
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
    <TaxCode>Tax</TaxCode>
    <TaxPercentage>0.00</TaxPercentage>
                </SalesOrderItemRet>
                <SalesOrderItemRet>
    <ListID>5757741489887019265</ListID>
    <TxnLineID>2</TxnLineID>
    <Attribute>Red/Wht/Bl</Attribute>
    <Commission>0.00</Commission>
    <Desc1>Wet Suit</Desc1>
    <Discount>0.00</Discount>
    <DiscountPercent>0.00</DiscountPercent>
    <ExtendedPrice>243.00</ExtendedPrice>
    <ExtendedTax>0.00</ExtendedTax>
    <ItemNumber>310</ItemNumber>
    <Price>121.50</Price>
    <PriceLevelNumber>3</PriceLevelNumber>
    <Qty>2.00</Qty>
    <Size>XL</Size>
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
    <TaxCode>Tax</TaxCode>
    <TaxPercentage>0.00</TaxPercentage>
                </SalesOrderItemRet>
                <SalesOrderItemRet>
    <ListID>5757743289578979585</ListID>
    <TxnLineID>3</TxnLineID>
    <Attribute>Red/Wht/Bl</Attribute>
    <Commission>0.00</Commission>
    <Desc1>Wet Suit</Desc1>
    <Discount>0.00</Discount>
    <DiscountPercent>0.00</DiscountPercent>
    <ExtendedPrice>121.50</ExtendedPrice>
    <ExtendedTax>0.00</ExtendedTax>
    <ItemNumber>312</ItemNumber>
    <Price>121.50</Price>
    <PriceLevelNumber>3</PriceLevelNumber>
    <Qty>1.00</Qty>
    <Size>MED</Size>
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
    <TaxCode>Tax</TaxCode>
    <TaxPercentage>0.00</TaxPercentage>
                </SalesOrderItemRet>
                <SalesOrderItemRet>
    <ListID>5757742417658675457</ListID>
    <TxnLineID>4</TxnLineID>
    <Attribute>Red/Wht/Bl</Attribute>
    <Commission>0.00</Commission>
    <Desc1>Wet Suit</Desc1>
    <Discount>0.00</Discount>
    <DiscountPercent>0.00</DiscountPercent>
    <ExtendedPrice>243.00</ExtendedPrice>
    <ExtendedTax>0.00</ExtendedTax>
    <ItemNumber>311</ItemNumber>
    <Price>121.50</Price>
    <PriceLevelNumber>3</PriceLevelNumber>
    <Qty>2.00</Qty>
    <Size>LRG</Size>
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
    <TaxCode>Tax</TaxCode>
    <TaxPercentage>0.00</TaxPercentage>
                </SalesOrderItemRet>
            </SalesOrderRet>
        </SalesOrderQueryRs>
    </QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
</QBPOSXML>
```

I'm using this code but it returns null and I couldn't find a way to access the elements or nodes in it
Note: I'm serializing the xml to json and then I'm doing the dynamic deserialization - but it didn't work with me,

```
 string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\testxml.txt");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            string jsonval = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
            dynamic res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonval);

            string f = res.CustomerListID;
```

Comment: XML does not equal JSON

Comment: @DavidWright I'm serializing the xml to json and then I'm doing the deserialization - check the code at the end of the question

Comment: You might want to delete this question, or remove it, because it appears it contains sensitive data. Including phone numbers and addresses..

Comment: It looks like you cut sections of the xml out of the original and the posted xml doesn't make a lot of sense.  I recommend you look at the xml in a xml reader to understand the structure.  I usually use the Visual Studio Tool.  Using VS menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml file.  Then paste xml into window.

Comment: @MichaelG it's a sample data from QB POS it's not real data, no worries

Comment: @jdweng yes it's part of it, i gave this xml as an example, all i'm trying is to deserialize the xml content into List of T objects so i can extract the data from them easily

Comment: There is absolutely, positively and utterly no need to serialize and than deserialize to and from JSON to get your C# List of stuff. That is like saying, I want to travel from Los Angeles to San Francisco by way of China!

Comment: This set of steps is related to the code sample, if there is can you suggest please? @CJohnson

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed.  If I post it to https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator I get an error `XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </SalesOrderQueryRs>. Line Number 270, Column 15`.   https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ generates the same error: `Line 270 Column 15: The element type "SalesOrderQueryRs" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</SalesOrderQueryRs>"`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked with something similar and newtonsoft.com taught me a lot.
For your situation you might what to try and look at [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm) as it deserialize a collection AKA a list.
Here's the sample from the site:

```
string json = @"['Starcraft','Halo','Legend of Zelda']";

List<string> videogames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", videogames.ToArray()));
// Starcraft, Halo, Legend of Zelda
```

You may have to change a few parameters to get what you want but this worked for me.

Comment: it doesn't work! because the type T in the list is unknown in my case -therefore this way is not going to work because i want to deserialize any xml to List of T

Comment: You'll have to do some digging in your case as mine was Json from a txt file but that site should give you the tools to finish what you need. My advice is to go through the site and other similar. Also here is another question similar that may help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication45
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Node(FILENAME);
        }

    }
    public class Node
    {
        public static Node root = null;

        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Node> children { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> dict { get; set; }

        public Node() { }
        public Node(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

            XElement xRoot = doc.Root;
            root = new Node();
            RecursiveParse(xRoot, root);
        }
        public void RecursiveParse(XElement xParent, Node node)
        {
            node.name = xParent.Name.LocalName;

            foreach (XAttribute attribute in xParent.Attributes())
            {
                if (node.dict == null) node.dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                node.dict.Add(attribute.Name.LocalName, (string)attribute);
            }
            foreach (XElement element in xParent.Elements())
            {
                if (element.HasElements)
                {
                    Node child = new Node();
                    if (node.children == null) node.children = new List<Node>();
                    node.children.Add(child);
                    RecursiveParse(element, child);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (node.dict == null) node.dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    node.dict.Add(element.Name.LocalName, (string)element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```